# AWS Cloudwatch Agent in a docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to set up Amazon Cloudwatch Agent to my docker as a container. This is an **OnPremise** installation so it's running locally, not inside AWS Kubernetes or anything of the sorts.

I've set up a basic dockerfile, agent.json and .aws/ folder for credentials and using `docker-compose build` to actually set it up, then launch it, but I am running into constant problems because Docker does not contain or run `systemctl` so I cannot run the service using AWS own documentation command:

```
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m onPremise -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json -s
```

This will fail on an error when I try to run the container:

```
cloudwatch_1  | /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl: line 262: systemctl: command not found
cloudwatch_1  | unknown init system
```

I've tried to run the /start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent inside /bin as well, but no luck. No documentation on this.

Basically the issue is **how can I run this as  a service or a process in the foreground?** Anyone have any clues? Otherwise the container won't stay up. Below is my code:

**dockerfile**

```
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20190508
RUN yum -y install https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
COPY agent.json /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json
CMD /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m onPremise -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json
```

**agent.json**

```
{
    "agent": {
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
        "region": "eu-west-1",
        "logfile": "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log",
        "debug": true
    }
}
```

.aws/ folder contains config and credentials, but I never got as far for the agent to actually try and make a connection.

Answer (score 2):

just use the official image `docker pull amazon/cloudwatch-agent` it will handle all the things for you; REF: [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/cloudwatch-agent)

if you insist on using your own, try the following:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20190508
RUN yum -y install https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
COPY agent.json  /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/default_linux_config.json
ENV RUN_IN_CONTAINER=True
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/start-amazon-cloudwatch-agent"]
```

Comment: Can you provide the documentation as well ? on how to use it as it seems there is no documentation provided on docker hub

Comment: you just need to map your conf file ` -v /path/config.json:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/default_linux_config.json`

Comment: This does not work on Docker, just on Kubernetes. It assumes you are launching inside an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AWS official Docker Image, here is the example of the docker compose

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  agent:
    image: amazon/cloudwatch-agent:1.247350.0b251814
    volumes:
      - ./config/log-collect.json:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/default_linux_config.json # agent config
      - ./aws:/root/.aws # required for authentication
      - ./log:/log # sample log
      - ./etc:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc # for debugging the config of AWS of container
```

From config above, only the first 2 volume sync required.
Number 3 & 4 is for debug purpose.

If you interested in learning what each volumes does, you can read more at https://medium.com/@gusdecool/setup-aws-cloudwatch-agent-on-premise-server-part-1-31700e81ab8